# Yahoo Mail on iPhone won't let me delete email

Tags: email, yahoo

Suddenly, my yahoo on iPhone won't let me respond to or delete any email?  What have I done?

Comment: Is this problem encountered while using the iPhone's built-in Mail app, or using Yahoo's Mail app?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are signed in. Sometimes you get disconnected and the auth mechanism doesn't re-authenticate you. (IMAP auth) *assuming you are using the Mail.app)

Worst case, you can delete your yahoo mail setup and re-configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iOS 9 upgrade my yahoo account wouldn't let me delete emails through the apple mail app. I tried deleting the account and adding it again but still no luck. Then I found the following site and it fixed the problem. http://www.macissues.com/2015/01/22/fix-mail-unable-to-move-messages-on-your-iphone-or-ipad/

Yay!  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Go into mail, touch accounts, go to advance touch the email account, make sure draft is checked and not trash can, check send
And email. This fixed the I can't send this email to trash. Apple couldn't fix it nor Verizon. This is in a iPhone 7s